# How do I create property for subclass of Apple's class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to access an instance of [SVSegmentedControl](https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl.)

It's a subclass of UIControl.

I created that instance during viewDidLoad

```
SVSegmentedControl *mySC = [[SVSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Normal", @"Limosine", @"Any", nil]];
```

It does have a method `- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl {` which I will be able to access the instance when the value is changed. But how do I access the instance(mySC) at other parts of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a property in your UIViewController, and instead of creating a new instance variable, set the property to the newly initialised segmented controller. And from there on you can access it outside the viewDidLoad's scope.

Edit...

You really need to learn how to propertize / setter & getter a variable rather than asking people to post code for you.

Below the `}` in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SVSegmentedControl *control;
```

Top of the implementation file

```
@synthesize control;
```

To set it:

```
self.control = [[[SVSegmentedControl alloc] init...] autorelease];
```

It should be set to `nil` in the dealloc method.